# Tables won't show in SQL server 2008 object explorer

Tags: sql-server

When trying to expand the tables on a database in the object explorer I get the following error:

“A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.
”

The database was recently restored from a SQL server 2000 box.  I can see two tables that are in the sysobjects catalogue but I can not drop or select them as it says the object does not exist.

Comment: What do the logs for the SQL Server instance say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seemed to fix the issue was that the rogue tables had an owner that was a SQL server login account which was recreated but no schema was recreated.  I recreated the schema which then let me browse the tables in the object explorer. From there I was able to delete the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running DBCC CHECKDB?